# Swift model not reading data from Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I have a base model called `Requirements` and another more specific model called `AccountRequirements`.

When I try to read the `currentDeadline` property, if i use `Requirements` it works fine. If I use `AccountRequirements` it comes out as `nil`.

I do not understand why. I'm guessing it has to do somehow with the `class`. I always use `struct` in my models but since I can not inherit from a `struct` I'm using `class` here.

```
class Requirements: Codable {
    var commonProperty: String

    // works
    var currentDeadline: Int?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case commonProperty = "common_property"

        case currentDeadline = "current_deadline"
    }
}

class AccountRequirements: Requirements {
    // doesnt work 
    var currentDeadline: Int?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case currentDeadline = "current_deadline"
    }
}
```

I decode data like this:

```
documentReference.addSnapshotListener { [self] documentSnapshot, error in
    guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
        self.error = error!.localizedDescription
        return
    }
    
    self.user = try? document.data(as: Requirements.self)
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the exact same property in the subclass as you have in the superclass? How do you decode the data?

Comment: It's only in one of them, just for demonstration purposes i put it on both. I updated my question on how I decode data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to decode it as the subclass then you need to give that class and not the superclass to `document.data(as:)`. You also need to implement `init(from:)` for the subclass to decode it properly

```
required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    currentDeadline = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .currentDeadline)
    try super.init(from: decoder)
}
```

Below is an example with a hardcoded json value

```
let data = """
    { "common_property": "Some text",
      "current_deadline": 42
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!


do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Requirements.self, from: data)
    print(type(of: result), result.commonProperty)
    let result2 = try JSONDecoder().decode(AccountRequirements.self, from: data)
    print(type(of: result2), result2.commonProperty, result2.currentDeadline ?? "")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

> Requirements Some text
> AccountRequirements Some text 42

Comment: Great!, its working for me also.. so i need to do this manually for each of the properties i want right? Is there another simpler way to do this, maybe via structs ? the idea is that i need to have a base model and a child model with some extra properties.

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to use struct instead of class and copy the properties of the old superclass into all struct’s. You get some duplicate properties but you will have much less custom code to implement, maybe even none.

Comment: thats what i just did... well instead of coping i put everything in one and those who are not common are optional so even if they are not there its still ok.